# Where did the pentagon with the minimum size of 0.2cm go?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes, polygon

I would like to draw five nested pentagons.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \size in {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1} {
    \node[regular polygon, draw, regular polygon sides=5, minimum size=\size cm] at (0, 0) {};
  }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But I only see four pentagons; why? If I change to  `\foreach \size in { 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1,1.2}`, it is well. Where did the pentagon with the minimum size of 0.2cm go? By the way, is there a better drawing approach? For instance, I'd like to add some new vertices, like in the example below.  The shapes for nodes above don't seem very conducive to further manipulation, such as adding more vertices or edges, unless I add new vertices  at the positions of their 5 endpoints.

[image]

The final picture looks like this.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: 2 mm is quite small: why don‘t you draw it bigger, as you already tried? // nodes are intended to hold text, which means you kind of abuse their shape. You could try to simply \draw your polygons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is there, but it happens that it is covered by the pentagon of the next size (0.4 cm). To see this set in the pentagon node the option `inner sep` to zero:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
 \foreach \size in {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1} 
 {
    \node[regular polygon, draw, regular polygon sides=5, 
          minimum size=\size cm, 
          inner sep=0pt]    % <---
          at (0, 0) {};
  }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A very nice explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers gave you already the solution to your stated problem (`inner sep` needs to be zero or you use a shape where you possibly shouldn't).

If you're drawing graphs you should use nodes for vertices and connect them with edges.
TikZ even has an extra library for it where you don't have to write `\node` and `edge` but can use a special syntax. With the `graphs.standard` library it also provides handy graph macros which you can use here as well.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\tikz[line width=.2mm]
  \graph[
    nodes={shape=circle, fill=red, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+4pt, outer sep=+0pt},
    n=5, phase=90, counterclockwise, empty nodes,
  ]{
    \foreach \i in {1, ..., 5}{
      subgraph C_n[name=penta\i, radius=\i*2mm]
    },
    \foreach \i in {1, ..., 5}{
      penta1 \i --[bend right=40, looseness=.8] penta5 \i
    }
  };
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Nice.  It is also good for my new question; see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699913/improvements-in-jagged-edges-and-layers. Until now, I'm not clear why my approach has jagged edges there while yours doesn't.  Qrrbrbirlbel said that this is because of my PDF renderer/viewer.

Comment: I just found you are same person. Haa…

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to draw it. Two remarks:

- 0 deg starts to the right, so I manually added 90 deg for simplicity
- I used a line width of 1 mm, to emphasize, how small your drawing actually is ...

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r in {.2,.4,.6,.8,1}
        \draw[line width=1mm] (90:\r)--(162:\r)--(234:\r)--(306:\r)--(378:\r)--cycle;
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be conducive to further drawing