# Improvements in jagged edges and layers

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to draw a graph, but due to layering issues, some vertices are below the lines, while others are above. I want to uniformly place the lines beneath the vertices.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r in {.2,.4,.6,.8,1} {
        \foreach \a in {90,162,234,306,378} {
            \draw[line width=0.2mm] (\a:\r) -- ({\a+72}:\r);
            \draw[line width=0.2mm, smooth] (\a:0.2) to [bend right=40, looseness=0.8] (\a:1);
            \fill[red] (\a:\r) circle (2pt);
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So, I modified the code as follows, but it seems that there are many 'for' loops. Is it possible to accomplish the task with as little code as possible?

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \r in {.2,.4,.6,.8,1} {
        \draw[line width=0.2mm] (90:\r)--(162:\r)--(234:\r)--(306:\r)--(378:\r)--cycle;
        \foreach \a in {90,162,234,306,378} {
           
            \draw[line width=0.2mm,smooth]  (\a:0.2) to [bend right=40,looseness=0.8]  (\a:1) ;
          
        }
    }
    \foreach \r in {.2,.4,.6,.8,1} {
       \foreach \a in {90,162,234,306,378}{
          \fill[red] (\a:\r) circle (2pt);
          }
    }
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Another question:** I've noticed that the 'bend right' and 'looseness' options result in jagged lines when drawing curves, which surprised me.

I use `MiKTeX` on  Windows 10.

Comment: The jagged lines are not TeX's or TikZ's fault. This is your PDF renderer/viewer.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you.  Do you mean this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361098/tikz-pdf-preview-jagged-lines-with-cycle 
Do you know of any good solutions? This situation is rare in my previous drawings.